# Slang question, what does mean by "horse"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, slang

I've been just happened to have been listening Britney Spears's [**Oops! I did it again**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CduA0TULnow&list=FLDUi4OEEh1WnwTT5CYPbE-Q&index=34), and what does the mars lander says "Oh there horse" at 0:20?

From the start

> The navigator : First, the Mars lander, report the status, please.
>
> Mars lander : Mars lander here. Gravity device status is effective. Watch the status 90%.
>
> The navigator : Any sign of habitation?
>
> Mars lander : Not so much is there. **Oh, there horse.**

What does he mean by that expression?

Thank you.

Comment: The supposed astronaut says  "Woah there horse..."

Comment: @MaxW Thank you. I wish if you kindly understand if you don't know a particular expression, listening could be also harder for non native speakers.

Comment: Whoa there horse. Not" woah

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> "Woah, there, horsey!"

It's an idiom that means "hold on a second" or "something is happening" or "let's stop what we are doing and pay attention to this!"

There is also:

> "Hold your horses!"

which means "slow down!"

And

> "Horse of a different color"

which means "a thing to which what we were just speaking of does not apply".

This is American English slang.   It comes from films known as"westerns" - films set in early America when there was a "frontier" - national Western border.   There are lots of actual horses in them. :)

Comment: People also say, "Whoa, Nellie!" "Whoa" is the standard command taught to horses, meaning "stop." "Nellie" is assumed to be the name of a horse, because the command "whoa" was given. "Nellie" isn't a standard horse name, but the context and the "country" (rural, farm) feeling associated with the name make it obvious that Nellie is a horse.

Comment: Nellie was in fact an old popular horse name.   Nellie Morse was a famous actual horse who won the 1924 Preakness.

Comment: ls it possible that the lander literally saw 'horse'? We don't expect to see horses on Mars though.

Comment: Whoa, not woah. Hold your horses. is a very old expression used when people still had horse-drawn carriages. It means bring the horses to a standstil and today just means wait a minute, don't go so fast.